# Send array to MySql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Currently I have a PHP program that grabs the text data off a web URL and saves it as an array.  Here is the code:

```
$handler = fopen('URL', 'r');

if ($handler){
    while (!feof($handler)){
        $line[] = fgets($handler);
    }
    fclose($handler);    
 }
```

Here is what a few lines of the array look like when printed:

```
9,632,1,44,Xi1esF8,28446,26377421,DK,C,0,0,0,1,0                              
9,632,2,320,i am,34977,24706164,EvOsso,C,0,0,0,1,0                               
9,632,3,352,Darwins Immaculate Selection,17357,23463949,MONSTERS,D,0,0,0,1,0
```

Each line is an array of $line[0], $line[1], $line[2] etc.

I want to put this into MySQL so that each piece of data after each ',' is a new column and each new line is a new row in MySQL.  So the MySQL DB has 14 columns and as many rows as data in the file has.

I'm not sure exactly how to code php to connect to the MySQL database and input each column based on a "," separator and each array ($line[0], $line[1], $line[2]) is a new row in MySQL.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Connecting to the database, or writing the data?

Comment: Writing the data.  I can connect just fine but what is the syntax to tell it to put each data item in a new row after each "," and each array is a new row?  So there are 14 columns and as many rows as needed in the database.

Comment: You need to look at `explode` to split the file into lines, and then each line into columns - you might be able to use `str_getcsv()` to do all the hard work http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Then, have a look at using prepared statements with PDO; you can pass an array of values directly to the database using prepared statements, and it'll all be escaped properly for you.

Comment: So instead of using the $line[] I should use $line because I can't explode an array?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily implode and explode and finally use a for loop to store every data separated by comma into database as different rows.

first you need to put your array values to a string so :

```
  $conn=mysql_connect("host_name","user_name","password") or error("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("db_name");

  $array=array("something","something","something");//this is the array you have.
  $string=implode(",",$array); // you need to implode array and store that as string.
```

now you need to explode your $string by comma again to put them in for loop to store into db.

```
  $str=explode(',',$string);
```

now you just make your query with a for loop.

```
  foreach($str as $strs)
  {
  $query = "INSERT INTO table_names(id, column_name)
               VALUES
               ('', '".$strs."')";
  mysql_query($query,$conn); 

  }
```

Comment: what is the $i=0 and the $i++ for?  Doesn't the foreach already step through each array element?

Comment: sorry in this case you dont need it , just if you need to use if condition you'll need it.again sorry

Comment: I dont think that code puts each array location in a different column?  I need each array location to be its own column.

Comment: so in the above 9,632,1,44,Xi1esF8,28446 each number after the coma needs to be in each column of its own.

Comment: I may have stumbled upon an answer to my own question: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$myFile'" .      " INTO TABLE ranksfeed_temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','